# Cloudera Manager API - how to deploy the default configuration?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager

I am trying to set up a cluster with the Cloudera Manager API. So far, I have added a service (HDFS) and roles (1 NN, 2 DN, 1 SNN). However they don't come with any kind of configuration.

When I add services/roles via the Web GUI, they come with default configuration. Is there a way to do the same via the API (add service with default configuration). If not, where do I need to put configuration files? A quick find revealed multiple locations where configuration xmls seem to live.

Answer (score -2):

> Cloudera Manager does it right what exactly needed in this case. If
>   you still want to change any configuration you can do it all through CM 
>   manager UI.
>   `Service=> Configuration=>Change any config=>Save=> Restart.`
>
> If you still want to make some changes via API it's located here

```
http://cloudera-scm_server_name:7180/static/apidocs/
```